# Comparing Lists with scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am starting a new project using Scala and Akka and am having trouble writing tests. In my tests I am checking the equality of two `List` objects using `should equal`:

```
actualBook should equal (expectedBook)
```

Everything in my test suite compiles and runs, but the tests fail with the following message:

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: List(BookRow(A,100.0,10.6)) did not equal List(BookRow(A,100.0,10.6))
```

Clearly the tests are passing (i.e., both `List` objects contain the same contents). Not sure if this is relevant or not, but `actualBook` and `expectedBook` have the same hash code (and `actualBook(0)` and `expectedBook(0)` also have the same hash code).

I am wondering if the problem is due to...

1. my using the incorrect comparison operator
2. the fact that I have not explicitly defined a way to compare `BookRow` objects.

For reference here is the code for my tests:

package lob

```
import cucumber.api.DataTable
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import cucumber.api.java.en.{When, Then}

class OrderBookSteps {

  val orderTypes = OrderType.all()

  val buyBook: OrderBook = new OrderBook(Bid, orderTypes)

  val sellBook: OrderBook = new OrderBook(Ask, orderTypes)

  @When("""^the following orders are added to the "(.*?)" book:$""")
  def ordersAddedToBook(sideString: String, orderTable: DataTable) {

    val (side, book) = getBook(sideString)

    val orders = orderTable.asList[OrderRow](classOf[OrderRow]).toList.map(
  r => LimitOrder(r.broker, side, r.volume, r.price.toDouble))
    orders.foreach(book.add)
  }

  @Then("""^the "(.*?)" order book looks like:$""")
  def orderBookLooksLike(sideString: String, bookTable: DataTable) {

    val (_, book) = getBook(sideString)
    val expectedBook = bookTable.asList[BookRow](classOf[BookRow]).toList
    val actualBook = book.orders().map(o => BookRow(o.broker, o.volume, orderTypes(o).bookDisplay))

    actualBook should equal (expectedBook)
  }

  def getBook(side: String) = side match {
    case "Bid" => (Bid, buyBook)
    case "Ask" => (Ask, sellBook)
  }

  case class OrderRow(broker: String, volume: Double, price: String)

  case class BookRow(broker: String, volume: Double, price: String)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution, although I don't understand why it works! I just needed to replace:

```
case class OrderRow(broker: String, volume: Double, price: String)

case class BookRow(broker: String, volume: Double, price: String)
```

with

```
private case class OrderRow(broker: String, volume: Double, price: String)

private case class BookRow(broker: String, volume: Double, price: String)
```

I would like to know why this works.

Answer (score 9):

You can try:

```
List(BookRow(A,100.0,10.6)).toSeq should equal (List(BookRow(A,100.0,10.6)).toSeq)
```

Or:

```
List(BookRow(A,100.0,10.6) should contain theSameElementsAs List(BookRow(A,100.0,10.6))
```

Assuming you have `BookRow` (normal class) equals overridden.

Comment: Neither worked. Same error message is returned for both.

Comment: Do you have the `BookRow` equals method overriden.

Comment: No. I have not overriden the equals method.

Comment: Well you need that to get the object comparison to work.

Comment: @nash_ag scalac pregenerates equals for case classes. https://gist.github.com/phadej/49bbeaef8715b2fca375

Comment: @OlegGrenrus Yes for the case class, but not for a normal class. Hence the question.

Comment: @nash_ag in the question `BookRow` is defined as case class?

Comment: @OlegGrenrus Sorry didn't have the code for reference when I answered it. That was the reason I asked for equals.

Comment: Agreed. `BookRow` is actually a case class (which has a default implementation of `equals`).